# PECL install fails

Tags: c, centos, pear, pecl

I have browsed every Google result, read all the forum posts about this error, but I cannot solve it.

When using PECL install for anything, I always end up getting this error:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
```

Everything else succeeds up to that point them bam!

I'm using CentOS 4.3, PEAR is the latest stable version, GCC is a stable and recent version. Everything is working as it should, but the C compiler always seems to error. I've tried to make tmp have the right privilages for the operation by temporarily enabling it using:

```
mount -o remount,exec,suid /tmp
```

But that doesn't work.

I've literally tried everything that has been suggested by to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Obvious question. *Can* you run C-compiled programs? Have you compiled a hello-world app (or anything else)? echo 'int main(){printf("Hello, world!\\n");}'|gcc -x c - -o hello && ./hello

Comment: [root@giglocator ~]# echo 'int main(){printf("Hello, world!\\n");}'|gcc -x c - -o hello && ./hello
<stdin>: In function 'main':
<stdin>:1: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'
Hello, world!\n
[root@giglocator ~]#

Comment: But yes I am sure it can run C-compiled apps, when not using PECL I have compiled a number of other apps.

Comment: Bump? Really need help here guys! Anyone got anymore ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cd ~
mkdir setups
cd setups
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/APC-3.1.2.tgz
tar -xvf APC-3.1.2.tgz
cd APC-3.1.2
phpize && ./configure --with-apxs && make
```

I quickly wrote that up and was able to install APC with a bit of manual work. Such as copying the module to PHP modules and adding the extension to the php.ini. Works perfectly now.

Comment: This has worked for me, to install the oauth extension I first needed to install: pcre-d, I did this with: yum install pcre pcre-d. Just in case someone has the same problem.

Answer (score 9):

I'm on Centos 5.3 and I was able to get PECL installers running (APC in my case) successfully by removing the noexec flag on both /tmp *and* /var/tmp

```
mount -o remount,exec,suid /tmp
mount -o remount,exec,suid /var/tmp
```

Doing this only on /tmp didn't work - I still received the error "checking whether the C compiler works... configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs."

Remember to run these remounts again with noexec after your install finishes.

Answer (score 2):

When I had similar problems installing the MongoDB driver, this worked for me:

```
sudo mkdir /root/tmp.pear
sudo mkdir /root/tmp.pear-build-root

sudo ln -s /root/tmp.pear /tmp/pear
sudo ln -s /root/tmp.pear-build-root /tmp/pear-build-root
```

Then:

```
sudo sudo pecl install XXX
```

(This doesn't open a security hole because only root can create executables in those two directories.)

Note that the following does **not** work for PECL:

```
sudo pear config-set temp_dir /var/tmp/pear/temp
```